# Projecting included objects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Im looking for a method to project included objects in EntityFramework Core in a way we can project objects (Select function):

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks()
    {
        return Json(new { data = await _db.Books.Select(b => _mapper.Map<BookDto>(b)).ToListAsync() });
    }
```

Here is my code where I tried to project included objects but its not valid:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetMessagesAsync()
    {
        var msgs = await _db.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.Sent).Include(m => _mapper.Map<AppUserDto>(m.AppUser)).ToListAsync();
        return Json(new { data = msgs });
    }
```

EDIT1:
I want to project included AppUser objects into AppUserDto.

EDIT2:

```
public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Book, BookDto>();
        CreateMap<BookDto, Book>();

        CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
        CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>();

        CreateMap<Reservation, ReservationDto>();
        CreateMap<ReservationDto, Reservation>();

        CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserDto>();
        CreateMap<AppUserDto, AppUser>();
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your mapper set up correctly you should be able to just do the following:

```
var msgs = await _db.Messages
     .OrderBy(m => m.Sent)
     .Include(m => m.AppUser)
     .Select(m => _mapper.Map<MessageDto>(m))
     .ToListAsync();
```

So your `MessageDto` will need to have `AppUserDto AppUser` property among others.

Comment: Here is the point that I want to project included objects of class AppUser -> AppUserDto

Comment: Are you using automapper?

Comment: Yes, I created MappingProfile "CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserDto>();"

Comment: Do you have some  `CreateMap<Message, MessageDto> mapping? If yes please add code for both classes.

Comment: Proposed code will project Message objects into MessageDto

Comment: Yes. And want do you want? You don't want messages? You want just users?

Comment: Yes. I know how to project messages, but my problem is projecting these included Users:)

Comment: If your `MessageDto` type has  field for  user and you have set up the mapping to `AppUser` from `Message` entity then this projection should work.

Comment: @agajek777 Please add code for your `Message` and `MessageDto` types.

Comment: Worked! I used your code and changed "AppUser" property in MessageDto to "AppUserDto". Problem solved. Thank you.